# Suppose $F(x)=\int_c^x f(t)dt$ and $f$ is not defined at $x=c$. Is there an agreed upon convention as to what $F(c)$ should equal?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, convention

Suppose $F$ is a function of the form $F(x)=\int_c^x f(t)dt$ and $f$ is not defined at $x=c$. Is there an agreed upon convention as to what $F(c)$ should equal?

Firstly, given that $f$ is not defined at $c$, it *is* convention to denote $F(x)$ as equaling $\displaystyle \lim_{\varepsilon \to c^+}\int_{\varepsilon}^xf(t)dt$. It would appear, then, that there are two possibilities. The first possibility is that the limit exists; the second possibility is that it does not.

Two examples I have worked with are the functions $F(x)=\int_0^x\frac{-1}{\sqrt{t}}dt$ or $F(x)=\int_0^x\frac{1}{t}dt$. In the first case, $F(x)$ is a finite value. In the second case, $F(x)$ is undefined because for any $x \gt 0$, $\displaystyle \lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\varepsilon}^x \frac{1}{t}dt$ approaches infinity.

As such, perhaps it is reasonable for the first case to let $F(c)=0$...but for the second case, $F(c)$ should be simply undefined?

Comment: $\int_c^c f(t)dt=0$ regardless of what $f$ is. So $F(c)=0$ always. It is a matter of calculation, not some special definition. It doesn't mean that it is continuous though. And also formally $f(c)$ has to be defined if you want to calculate the integral. Even though the value doesn't matter (cause a single point is of measure $0$).

Comment: @freakish It's not true that $f(c)$ needs to be defined: the OP describes the precise definition of the improper integral $\int_c^x f(t)\,dt$ in that case.

Comment: @GregMartin his "convention" is not a proper definition of integral.

Comment: It is the precise definition of the improper integral that appears in standard calculus textbooks. Also, please don't make gender assumptions about users; defaulting to male pronouns contributes to the unwelcoming atmosphere for women and non-binary people in mathematis.

Comment: When "F(c) is undefined for any c > 0" then **there is no function F to consider**.

Comment: @GregMartin the only reasonable value for $\int_c^c$ is $0$. This coincides with both Riemann and Lebesgue, and probably every other integral definition out there. Integral from $c$ to $c$ is a proper integral, always well defined and calculable from the definition. Also, lol, I don't care about the "pronouns" crusade, I was referring to "OP" word, not his gender. But hey, you can fight whatever imaginary war you want.

Comment: Hey, @GregMartin. You have been very helpful with my previous posts, so I figured adding context may be helpful. I am working on an exercise that states that the function $F(x)=\int_1^x \frac{f(t)}{t}dt$ is *defined* on $x \geq 1$. I want to prove some things about $f$ and the way I need to exhaustively approach this is to address whether or not $f$ is defined at $1$. Both you and freakish are reputable users and both of you are saying opposite things regarding whether or not $f$ needs to be defined at $1$ (i.e. freakish would say that $F$ defined at $1$ implies this, whereas you would not).

Comment: @freakish did I correctly note what you would most likely say in my above comment? In particular, I am trying to determine if I need to consider the case where $\lim_{x \to 1^+}f(t)=\pm \infty$?

Comment: @S.C. is that an exercise from some book? If so then which one? Perhaps it was meant that $f$ is defined for $x\geq 1$? It should be explicitly stated whether proper or improper integral is considered, its an important distinction. After thinking about it more I think that the statement is ambiguous and it is impossible to answer that without clarification. While I still believe that $\int_c^c$ should be $0$, it actually would not coincide with improper integral definition, at least depending on how exactly you define it. So I'm sort of taking back what I said. Its an edge case.

Comment: @freakish yes, this is an exercise from Spivak's *Calculus 4th Ed* (Chapter 18 Problem 12).